# laravel How to delete database data after 5 minutes of adding?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Laravel How to delete database data after 5 minutes of adding?

```
Schema::create('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('country');
  $table->string('date');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: A CRON Job run every minute maybe to check and delete any rows older than 5 minutes

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#scheduling-shell-commands

Comment: How to connect scheduler to database timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this in [the scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#defining-schedules).(or can call a [**event**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events))

> **This gets the record for the last 5 minutes and deletes the data.**

```
$minutes  = Carbon::now()->subMinutes( 5 );
Listing::where('created_at', '<=', $minutes)->delete();
```

> And schedule it to [**`everyMinute()`**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options)

---

***Note:** I assumed you have a model called `Listing` or change according to it.*

Comment: write it like that?  class Listing extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
$minutes  = Carbon::now()->subMinutes( 5 );
Listing::where('created_at', '<=', $minutes)->delete();
}

Comment: @chikadze what? You need to write on schedule not in model

Comment: like that?protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $minutes  = Carbon::now()->subMinutes( 5 );
        $schedule->call(function (){
            DB::table('listings')->delete();
        })->cron(
            Listing::where('created_at', '<=', $minutes)->delete()
        );
    }

Comment: check this link https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#defining-schedules

Comment: Is it correct now?     $schedule->call(function () {
            $minutes  = Carbon::now()->subMinutes( 5 );
            Listing::where('created_at', '<=', $minutes)->delete();
        })->everyMinute();

Comment: Yes make sure you have the `Listing` model

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron job for this. You have to set cron job time to execute after 5 minutes and removed database which was created before 5 minutes.

Please refere:-
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling

Comment: How to connect scheduler to database timestamp?